# how can i get value of multiple checked box and perform increment using value from checked box

Tags: javascript, html

i can's seem to get the element by using id with query selector. Is there a way to check if the checkbox were checked using document.getelementbyId?

```
<script>
function checked(a,b,c){
    var marked = (a+b+c)
    document.write(marked);
}

function filled(){
    var value1 = document.querySelector("#1:checked").value;
    var value2 = document.querySelector("#2:checked").value;
    var value3 = document.querySelector("#3:checked").value;

    checked(value1,value2,value3);

    

}
```

```
<body>

<input class="chk1" id="1" type="checkbox" value="10"/>
<input class="chk2" id="2" type="checkbox" value="20"/>
<input class="chk3" id="3" type="checkbox" value="30"/>

<button name="submit" onclick="filled()" type="button" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" >Submit</button>


</body>
```

Comment: `id` cannot start with a number.

Comment: check console your see: *error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#1:checked' is not a valid selector.*

Comment: Also `document.querySelector("#id1:checked").value` would give you a `cannot access value of null` error if that checkbox is not checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDs aren't valid. Even if they were (such as if you changed them to start with a letter), if a checkbox isn't checked, the `querySelector` will return `null` (so accessing the `.value` won't work).

Remove the IDs and use `querySelectorAll` instead. To make things concise, I'd give them all a single class and then the `:checked` pseudo-selector combined with the class will select all checked boxes.

You should also really [avoid inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) if at all possible, they have they have way too many problems to be worth using nowadays.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.chk:checked');
  const sum = [...checkedBoxes].reduce((a, b) => a + Number(b.value), 0);
  console.log(sum);
});
```

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" value="10">
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" value="20">
<input class="chk" type="checkbox" value="30">

<button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Good answer with all the relevant points. I wish it would at least point out that inline event listeners shouldn't be used.

Comment: is there any reason why i shouldn't use inline event listerner?

Comment: Follow the link in the question for one example - they have an incredibly demented scope chain, in addition to tedious and error-prone quote escaping issues. Attach event listeners properly using Javascript with `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: if i have 5 input  do i have to put 5 dots inside const sum = [...checkedBoxes]

Comment: @Vaness Yes, the dots transform the NodeList to an array, and `.reduce` can only be called on an array. There are other methods, but using `.reduce` is probably the most concise and appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

using numbers, punctuation or special characters in the value of an ID may cause trouble in other contexts (e.g., CSS, JavaScript, regex).

For example, the following ID is valid in HTML5:

```
<div id="1"> ... </div>
```

However, it is invalid in CSS because selectors cannot be a digit or start with a digit but can be inbetween or end with a digit.

So just change the values of your ID attributes in your html and where u referenced them in your javascript.
Be sure to not miss any semi colons